# how to use preg_replace to remove all following style tag/pattern occurrences in a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to find a regex to match the following:

```
<style type="text/css"> .article-content{ position: relative;

padding-bottom: 140px;} .pane.pane-newsletter-contextual{ display: block;

bottom: 32px; position: absolute; left: 0px; margin-left: 0px; } </style>
```

I need the regex in order to pass it to preg_replace and remove it from a string.  I have basic knowledge of regex and tried this after reviewing the basic on http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

```
preg_replace("/<style\b[^>]*>(.*?)</style>/", "", $body);
```

However this line is giving the following error `Unknown modifier 't' in ...`

Also, I tried searching before positing the question and could not find any that is similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to escape the slash...

```
preg_replace("/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s", "", $body);
```

More info about the modifiers [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

As of why we need 2 backslashes, because we need a backslash character in the string to escape the slash.  And unfortunately, in PHP, we need a double backslash `\\` to represent a single backslash character in all single or double quoted strings.  It is not a must, but when things get complicated, it helps make things clearer.

Alternatively, you could choose a different character as the identifier.  For example,

```
preg_replace("|<style\b[^>]*>(.*?)</style>|s", "", $body);
```

This way, you could avoid escaping the slashes.

EDIT: Added modifier to make the replacement "work".

EDIT2: Added explanation of the double backslash in the pattern string.

EDIT3: Added an alternative.

Comment: thanks, that was one issue I presume. But it is not removing the string that matches.

Comment: Because the string is split into lines.  Try using the modifier "s".

Comment: thank you sir. Any particular reason you added 2 backslashes instead of 1? ...I have to really study this more. I missed it...

Comment: Added explanation to the double backslash.  ;)